# Connecting Hive Server2 using PHP

Tags: php, hadoop, hive

I wan to connect Hive Server2 Using PHP and for this I found the only option is [Apache Thrift](http://nousefor.net/55/2011/12/php/hbase-and-hive-thrift-php-client/) available.

But it works only for Hive Server1 not for Hive Server2. After searching more on it found, This is because the thrift server is expecting to authenticate via SASL when you open your transport connection. Hive Server 2 defaults to using SASL - unfortunately, PHP lacks a version of TSaslClientTransport (which is used as a wrapper around another TTransport object) which handles the SASL negotiation when you open your transport connection.

Is there any one who has succeeded on connecting hive server2 using php.

Comment: Could you find a way to connect to Hive server2 using PHP. I also have the same problem and could not find any document or working example. Please let me know if you find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    // set THRIFT_ROOT to php directory of the hive distribution
    $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = '/lib/php/';
    // load the required files for connecting to Hive
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . 'packages/hive_service/ThriftHive.php';
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . 'transport/TSocket.php';
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . 'protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php';
    // Set up the transport/protocol/client
    $transport = new TSocket('localhost', 10000);
    $protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);
    $client = new ThriftHiveClient($protocol);
    $transport->open();

    // run queries, metadata calls etc
    $client->execute('SELECT * from src');
    var_dump($client->fetchAll());
    $transport->close();

?>
```

Here is the documentation on apache website:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-PHP

Comment: This code sample is not compatible with hive server2